# Index multiple ranges in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, range

I know that this question occured multiple times in different variations, but I couldn't find anything that actually matched my problem.

The general idea: I have a list of event IDs. I go through an array to find the first and last time an event ID occurs. Then I use these indices to check if all elements are NaN in another array in the range of `first_time - 3` to `last_time + 3`. At the end I count how often all elements in this range are NaN in the second array.

```
counter=0
for event_ID in list_of_event_IDs:
    beginning_index, ending index = find_event_indices(some_array,event_ID) # +-3 is already added by this function
    if np.all(is_element_from_another_array_nan[beginning_index:ending_index]):
        counter += 1
```

This obviously results in quite some calls to `is_element_from_another_array_nan`.
My idea was to make all these calls in one go, once I know the index ranges.
For this I created an array of arrays that contains the indices:

```
indices_array = np.zeros(len(list_of_event_IDs), 2), dtype=int)

for row, event_ID in enumerate(list_of_event_IDs):
    indices_array[row, :] = find_event_indices(some_array,event_ID)

indices_array=array([[  34,   40],
                     [  49,   55],
                     [  83,   89],
                     [ 765,  775],
                      ............

is_element_from_another_array_nan=array([ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True])
```

My idea is to use something along the lines of
`counter = np.sum(np.all(is_element_from_another_array_nan[indices_array], axis=1))`, but this only checks the indices that are given explicitly in `indices_array` and not the range between them.
I could circumvent the entire problem by having an array that contains the ranges explicitly like

```
indices=array([[34,35,36,37,38,39,40],
               [49,50,51,52,53,54,55],
                ........
```

Here the problem is that the arrays inside the array will contain different amount of elements, therefore I can't use `np.zeros`. I could avoid this one by going with lists instead of numpy arrays, but I feel like I am missing something obvious.
Also I can't do `np.all((some_array==event_ID) & is_element_from_another_array_nan)` since this would neglect my +-3 window.
Has anyone an easy solution for my problem? I feel like I am missing something very obvious.

Comment: What's wrong with previous answers?  I think they say that you have to concatenate a list of arrays one way or other, whether you first do the slicing, or you first construct the multiple indexing `aranges`

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood something about the previous answers, but this would result in one single array, that would in my case contain a lot different True/False statements like
`result_array=array([ True,  True, False,...]`. Then I would still need to figure out if the every value for e.g. index 17-24 is NaN or not since everything is in one array instead of being split up into sub-arrays.